# ConEmu: How do I make a task automatically close after completing

Tags: conemu

I have the following task set up in ConEMU

TASKKILL /IM iexplore.exe /F

After the task runs, it leaves a console window open with a confirmation dialog "Press Enter or Esc to close console window".

Is there a way to make my task automatically close it's tab after performing its operations.

I tried using -cur_console and -new_console but these don't seem to do what I need.

Comment: http://conemu.github.io/en/NewConsole.html

Answer (score 24):

There is a setting *Confirm close* for that in *Settings* > *Integration* > *Default term*:

[image: Screenshot ConEmu Settings]

Answer (score 4):

According to [this documentation](https://conemu.github.io/en/NewConsole.html#syntax) you can use the `:n` switch:

```
n - disable ‘Press Enter or Esc to close console’
```

For example, the following task opens a new tab, performs a git pull on master and then automatically closes again:

```
-new_console:n cd C:\my_git_repo & git fetch --all & git checkout master & git pull
```

Watch out as it closes the tab even on non-successful status codes.